# export dataframe to new excel worksheet and also write specific values to specific sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I'm running into an issue that I think relates to needing to:

1. export a dataframe to a new Excel worksheet (created at time of export)
2. write specific values to an existing sheet in same workbook
3. Doing both of the above in a loop

I can get 1 and 3 to work by themselves, and I can get 2 and 3 to work by themselves, but when I try to do all three things it doesn't work.  I think there is some issue with the pandas to_excel using xlsxwriter engine conflicting with the sheets.write(row,column, value) to the same workbook.

For instance, this works by itself (note that I have the "writer" stuff to export dataframe to new sheet commented out):

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

loopList = ["A","B","C","D","E"]
data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]] 
counter = 1
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])
 
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('C:\\Test\\Test.xlsx')
totalsSheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Totals')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:\\Test\\Test.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter')

for sheets in loopList:
    
    #df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = sheets, index=False)
    totalsSheet.write(counter, counter, sheets + str(counter)) 
    counter+=1
    
#writer.save()
#writer.close()
workbook.close()
```

The above makes the test.xlsx workbook, with a Totals worksheet, with "A1", "B2", etc. in incrementing row/column.

Likewise, when I comment out the workbook stuff and UN comment the pandas-export dataframe to new sheets, that also works:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

loopList = ["A","B","C","D","E"]
data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]] 
counter = 1
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])
 
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('C:\\Test\\Test.xlsx')
totalsSheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Totals')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:\\Test\\Test.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter')

for sheets in loopList:
    
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = sheets, index=False)
    #totalsSheet.write(counter, counter, sheets + str(counter)) 
    counter+=1
    
writer.save()
writer.close()
#workbook.close()
```

The above gives me a new Test workbook with 5 sheets (A, B, C, etc.) with the same dataframe exported to each.

However, I can't seem to do both; depending on the order in which I have the lines that write to Excel, it still only does one or the other (I don't get errors, I just get a result that's not both things I'm trying to do).

Is there a way to accomplish both of these things in the same loop?

I'm using python 3.x.x.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not just run it in to separate loops that each open and close the file to ensure that it is available to each processes? Something like...

```py
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

loopList = ["A","B","C","D","E"]
data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]] 
counter = 1
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])

with pd.ExcelWriter('C:\\Test\\Test.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter') as writer: 
    for sheets in loopList: 
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = sheets, index=False)

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('C:\\Test\\Test.xlsx')
totalsSheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Totals')

for sheets in loopList: 
    totalsSheet.write(counter, counter, sheets + str(counter)) 
    counter+=1
    
workbook.close()
```

**Update**

Looking into it more, as the docs say xlsxwriter:

> cannot read or modify existing Excel XLSX files.

So what you were trying before was causing the overwrite to happen. However, if you look into the [docs more](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html) you will see that the key is to create the workbook object from the pd.ExcelWriter object. This will mean that both libraries can write to the file at the same time.

I installed xlsxwriter and the code below works for me:

```py
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

# data to write
loopList = ["A","B","C","D","E"]
data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]] 

# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])

# create the writer object
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# create the workbook object from the current writer object
# this means that pandas and xlsxwriter can both write to it
workbook = writer.book 
totalsSheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Totals')

# set the counter
counter = 1

# lopo through and use xlsx writer to write specific cells
for sheets in loopList: 
    totalsSheet.write(counter, counter, sheets + str(counter)) 
    counter+=1
    
# loop through generating new sheets and writing dfs to the file
for sheets in loopList: 
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = sheets, index=False)

# save the written data
writer.save()
```

Comment: This has the same issue; whichever one of those loops I put last, that's what the resulting file will be.  I had to include a "writer.save()" and "writer.close()" to get that loop to work, but the overall result is the same; if the ExcelWriter is the last loop, I get the excel workbook with the 5 sheets that have the dataframes.  If the totalsSheet is the last one, I get the workbook with "Totals"  tab, no other worksheets.

Comment: I've not used xlsxwriter before, but see the minor change I made to the edit. I think that might make a difference.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts, but that does not work either, I get the totals tab but nothing else.  It's as if xlsxwriter is interfering with itself if asked to do 2 things, like it overwrites whatever was done first.  I'm kind of surprised no one else is running into this issue, or that no one needs to export dataframes to multiple sheets and write values to one specific sheet all within a loop

Comment: No worries. I've had a further look and have solved it. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: This works, and I appreciate your help.  It's unfortunate that this must be done in separate loops, as I will basically be repeating all of the code in the loop twice, since a lot of what is written to the Totals page comes from the same type of data wrangling happening with the same source data and dataframes written out in the other loop.  This doesn't seem very pythonic.  But I'm glad to be able to at least accomplish this, thanks for the help.  If anyone else knows how to accomplish this in the same loop, I'd love to see it.  Thanks all

Comment: You don't have to do it in two loops I just wrote it like that for clarity. You could just do this in a single loop:
```
for sheets in loopList:
    totalsSheet.write(counter, counter, sheets + str(counter)) 
    counter+=1
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = sheets, index=False)
```